# Can't use Gizmo's in any view but camera view

Tags: modeling, transforms

This seems to be a new bug with Blender 2.79. I've personally never had it happen before and now it's happened twice in a very short period of time.

For no apparent reason, my gizmos (translate, rotate, scale) will stop being selectable in any view but camera view.

Going into the camera view by pressing Numpad 0 will allow me to use the gizmo's but as soon as I exit camera view, I can no longer use them.

This has happened with two files so far and to continue using gizmo's I've had to append the objects in that file over to a new file. I've tried numerous things to try to restore the gizmos but have had no success.

Have I managed to accidently press some key which is stopping me from using gizmos or is this a bug?

Comment: Is it just that the object's don't move when you click the manipulators or is it that the manipulators aren't being selected at all (ie. they should disappear as a transformation happens)?

Comment: @RayMairlot The manipulators aren't being selected at all. Clicking on them just moves my 3D cursor to them.

Comment: Have you tried restoring Blender to the factory defaults?

Answer (score 1):

It just happened to me (not first time) and I've found the issue.

I don't know why, but you only have to uncheck Lock to Cursor on 3D View's Properties Tab. You may accidentally checked it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for sharing that. I actually haven't had the issue again since making my last post, but if I happens again I'll definitely check that setting to make sure it's not enabled.

Thanks

Comment: Oh, I guess you can't mark my answer as correct then :/